# Javascript not firing in Wordpress 4.6.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

The code below is working in a jfiddle, but once on my WordPress site it's not firing. I am updated to 4.6.1. I can't seem to find any errors in the console, either. Any ideas?

CSS:

```
<style>.bluebg { background: cyan; }</style>
```

HTML:

```
<nf-field>
    <div class="nf-field-container textbox-container  label-left ">
       <div class="nf-before-field"><nf-section></nf-section></nf-section></div>
       <div class="nf-field"><div id="nf-field-8-wrap" class="field-wrap textbox-wrap nf-pass" data-field-id="8">   
            <div class="nf-field-label">
            <label for="nf-field-8" class="">Full Name <span class="ninja-forms-req-symbol">*</span></label></div>
                <div class="nf-field-element">
                <input id="nf-field-8" name="nf-field-8" class="ninja-forms-field nf-element" value="" type="text">
            </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="nf-after-field"><nf-section><div class="nf-input-limit"></div><div class="nf-error-wrap nf-error"></div></nf-section>
        </div>
    </div>
</nf-field>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script>
$('input.nf-element').bind('focus blur', function () {
    $(this).closest('nf-field').find('.nf-field-container').toggleClass('bluebg');
});
</script>
```

**UPDATE**

It looks like the problem is in the plugin that is generating the HTML, not the javascript I'm using. If I paste the same HTML in manually, that input field does change the parent class, but none of the fields that the form plugin generates (NinjaForms) will change.

I'm not sure if that's out of scope for assistance here, but if anyone has any ideas why that would be, I'd be appreciative!

Comment: How are you including this script? Have you verified that it is actually been included/requested by the browser?

Comment: wordpress usually uses `jQuery.noConflict()` which makes `$` undefined. Check browser console for errors

Comment: Could you include the fiddle?

Comment: Sorry, here is the jfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ygdba1Lq/#   I am seeing no errors in the console on the Wordpress site.

Answer (score 0):

To account for wordpress likely using [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) try changing to:

```
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    $('input.nf-element').on('focus blur', function() {
      $(this).closest('nf-field').find('.nf-field-container').toggleClass('bluebg');
    });
  });    
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: There is a space before 'container' in your code that I removed, then it works in a fiddle. But not on my Wordpress site. To further clarify, it worked before updating Wordpress to the latest version!

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace "$" with "jQuery".

Comment: That works in the fiddle, but not on my site. Something must be blocking the script from firing, but I'm not seeing any console errors.